# Using the sequential Criterion, give a proof that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, where: $f(x) = -1$, $x \leq 0$ or $x$, $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using the sequential Criterion, give a proof that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}-1 & \text{if } x < 0\\
\ \ \ x & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Define a sequence $(x_n)$ as follows: $x_n= \frac{1}{2n}$ for $n$ even, $x_n = -\frac{1}{2n}$ for $n$ odd.

*Added:* Here $x_n \to 0.$ On the other hand $f(x_n)$ is not convergent. For $n$ even we have $f(x_n)=\frac{1}{2n} \to 0,$ where as for all $n$ odd $f(x_n) = -1.$